# "Play with this data!" not showing up for my plotly.js plot

Tags: javascript, plotly

I was under the assumption the "Play with this data!" link was supposed the show up by default. Any ideas on why it may not appear? I am just working with a basic scatter plot.

Note that this code below is not standalone as is, it is just the excerpt that does the plotly work.

```
var xData = [];
var yData = [];
var h = results;
for(var k in h) {
    var localdate = k;
    var plotdate = moment(localdate).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
    xData.push(plotdate);
    if (currentPort === "t") {
        yData.push(CtoF(h[k]));
    } else {
        yData.push(h[k]);
    };
}
var plotdata = [
    {
        x: xData,
        y: yData,
        type: 'scatter',
        mode: 'markers+lines',
        line: {
            'color': HELIUM_BLUE
        },
        marker: {
            'symbol': 'circle',
            'color': HELIUM_PINK,
            'maxdisplayed': 50
        }
    }
];
var layout = {
    title: currentData,
    xaxis: {
        'title': 'Date / Time'
    },
    yaxis: {
        'title': title
    }
};
Plotly.newPlot(plotHolder, plotdata, layout);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add `{showLink: true}` as the fourth argument (after `layout`). I guess the [default value](https://plot.ly/javascript/configuration-options/) changed from `true` to `false`.
If you want to change the caption of the button, use `{showLink: true, "linkText": "Play with this data"}`

```js
var xData = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var yData = [10, 1, 25, 12, 9];

var plotdata = [
    {
        x: xData,
        y: yData,
        type: 'scatter',
        mode: 'markers+lines',
    }
];
var layout = {
    title: 'Edit me',
    xaxis: {
        'title': 'x'
    },
    yaxis: {
        'title': 'y'
    }
};
Plotly.newPlot(plotHolder, plotdata, layout, {showLink: true, "linkText": "Play with this data"});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id='plotHolder'>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this has worked for me. Do you by chance know how I would change the text of the link? It defaults to "Edit data"

Comment: Thank you for the assistance!